# SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Users' with unique index

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am using Entity Framework 6 + C# + WPF. I have such models (ok, a bit simpler version)

```
    public class User
    {
        [Key]
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "VARCHAR")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        [Index("UserName", IsUnique = true)]
        public string UserName { get; set; }
    }

    public class LogEntry : IEquatable<LogEntry>
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public long UserId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual User User { get; set; }= new User();
        public string Message {get;set;}

    }
```

When I try to add new `LogEntries` into the database, I am getting an error:

> SqlException: Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Users' with unique index UserName

But, I do not want to add the referenced user to the database...

`LogEntry.UserId` has the id of already existing row in table `Users`, just like `LogEntry.User` has the id of an existing row and `userName` of an existing record. I just want to save a reference (foreign key) to that table, not to add new record.

```
user = context.Users.FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserName == user.UserName);

foreach (LogEntry item3 in items)
{
    item3.User = user;
    item3.UserId = user.UserId; ;
}
.
.
.
context.Logs.AddRange(logs); 
context.SaveChanges();
```

How can I do it? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF thinks you want to add a new user to the DB because the `User` property is being assigned with what it thinks is a new user. If you just make it null but assign `UserId` to the correct value it should retain the reference without adding a new user.

```
foreach (LogEntry item3 in items)
{
    item3.User = null; //Don't need to do this if it's already null
    item3.UserId = user.UserId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this : `user = context.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefault(c => c.UserName == user.UserName);` so that your "user" is not cached on your "context".

Then save it:

```
                context.Users.Attach(user);
                context.Entry(user).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();
```